How do I find a partial match from a data table to an individual cell?
I'm trying to build a budgeting spreadsheet, and I want to automatically categorize expenses that have certain key words, if available. The output from the credit card company contains descriptions, and I want to build a generalized database of common expenses in categories, and build a lookup that'll pull the related category.
I'm linking below to an example spreadsheet that has some selected data to show what I'm trying to do.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-uWQLJJhFaXNwKj7iY4YdcmnaRpttTKh9nzkgDd6iU/edit?usp=sharing
Column C is what I want to use to look up the category. The categories are in J1:AJ6. What I want the output to be is in column I. Row 13 is a good example - Amazon puts a unique identifier at the end, so I just want AMZN to match from column Z and pull the category "Misc" in.
If you don't want to look at the sheet, below is a dummy representation of what I'm trying to do, even more simplified



CC Data Description
Desired Lookup Result
Misc
Food and Groceries
Pet
Travel
Entertainment
Fast Food




NETFLIX.COM
Entertainment
TARGET
H-E-B
CHEWY.COM
LYFT
NETFLIX.COM
CHICK-FIL-A


CHEWY.COM
Pet
AMZN
KROGER

UNITED
Prime Video
MCDONALD'S


DOUBLETREE NEWCASTLE

SH SALON


UBER




TARGET 00034215
Misc



HILTON




AMZN Mktp US*HB2XZ9AC3
Misc



THEPARKINGSPOT




MCDONALD'S F11327
Fast Food








LEGENDS@NISSAN-ZIPPIN









LYFT *1 RIDE 09-22
Travel











Here's one approach you may test out:
=map(C2:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(index(if(len(J2:AJ6)*search(J2:AJ6,Σ),J1:AJ1,)),3,1)))))



Awesome - so far this looks like it works! I'll have to go through and check to make sure it's picking up everything correctly, but at first glance, it looks solid.
Would you mind explaining how it works, basically? I've never seen Lambda used, for example.
